# Why DataView Lookup performance very slow?

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, find, dataview

In my winform project, I have a DataGrid with data binding.
DataSource is a DataTable, there are two columns, Id and Name
I want to find some data in dataGrid
At first, I use Find method, but when look up count is over 100, performance is very slow.

create a datatable

```
this._dt = new DataTable();
this._dt.Columns.Add("Id");
this._dt.Columns.Add("Name");

for (var i = 0; i < this.dataRowCount; i++)
{
    var row = this._dt.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = i;
    row["Name"] = "name is -->" + i;
    this._dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
this._dt.AcceptChanges();
```

1.use loop

```
private void FindByLoop(string propertName, string value)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this._dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = this._dt.Rows[i];
        if (row[propertName]?.ToString() == value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

2. use DataView

```
var currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[this._dt];
var collection = currencyManager.GetItemProperties();
var descriptor = collection.Find(propertName, true);
var index = ((IBindingList)currencyManager.List).Find(descriptor, value);
Debug.WriteLine(index);
```

Test when loop up count is 300

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        FindByLoop("Id", i.ToString());
    }
    var end = DateTime.Now;
    MessageBox.Show("Spend-->" + (end - start).Milliseconds.ToString());
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        FindByDataView("Id", i.ToString());
    }
    var end = DateTime.Now;
    MessageBox.Show("Spend-->" + (end - start).Milliseconds.ToString());
}
```

Result:
loop:59 ms
dataView: 569 ms

I want to find out another way such as create new DataView to avoid but still slow

There is a doc said need to create a new DataView when use Find method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataview-performance

So I changed code to this:

```
var dataView = new DataView(this.DataSource as DataTable);
```

Is my usage wrong? Thanks

Comment: How about finding the data in the original collection?

Why are you searching the UI for data instead of reacting to events that will pass you the object that the user interacted with?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with `start =` fire up your app and then explore the `sender` input to your event handler.

Also, use Stopwatch() to time things. Much more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, but reckon time you can see use the second way, very slow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I change old code to use the first way to just loop. It has better performance, I just want to know reason. I 'm reading source code now.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings. You shouldn't need to loop over ANYTHING. Look at the contents of the sender parameter.